# How to check if a JavaScript Object has a property name that starts with a specific string?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, identifier

Lets say I have javascript objects like this one:

```
var obj = {
    'addr:housenumber': '7',
    'addr:street': 'Frauenplan',
    'owner': 'Knaut, Kaufmann'
}
```

How can I check if the object has a property name that starts with `addr`? I’d imagine something along the lines of the following *should* be possible:

```
if (e.data[addr*].length) {
```

I tried `RegExp` and `.match()` to no avail.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can check it against the Object's keys using `Array.some` which returns a `bool`.

```
if(Object.keys(obj).some(function(k){ return ~k.indexOf("addr") })){
   // it has addr property
}
```

You could also use `Array.filter` and check it's length. But `Array.some` is more apt here.

Comment: Cheers to all! This one seems to be the shortest and most elegant way to do it.

Comment: @Edwin brilliant, even more elegant!

Comment: lol alright soon it'll be easier with fat arrow functions in ES6

Comment: @Edwin yeah.. `Object.keys(obj.some((k) => ~k.indexOf("addr"));`. Waiting for it to come :)

Comment: Me too Me too can't wait

Comment: What is the role of ~ here?

Comment: Note that with a very large object, it's not very efficient because `Object.keys()` is generated before the call with `some()`; it's more efficient to check property by property with a `for in`.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `Object.keys` function to get an array of keys and then use the `filter` method to select only keys beginning with `"addr"`.

```
var propertyNames = Object.keys({
    "addr:housenumber": "7",
    "addr:street": "Frauenplan",
    "owner": "Knaut, Kaufmann"
}).filter(function (propertyName) {
    return propertyName.indexOf("addr") === 0;
});
// ==> ["addr:housenumber", "addr:street"];
```

This gives you existence (`propertyNames.length > 0`) and the specific names of the keys, but if you just need to test for existence you can just replace `filter` with `some`.

Answer (score 6):

```
Obj = {address: 'ok', x:5}

Object.keys(obj).some(function(prop){
  return ~prop.indexOf('add')
}) //true
```

Comment: What is the Tilders functionality here?

Answer (score 1):

You can check this also with startsWith():

```
Object.keys(obj).some(i => { return i.startsWith('addr') })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myObject = {
    'prop1': 'value1',
    'xxxxx': 'value2'
};

var stringToCheck = 'addr';

for(var propertyName in myObject) {
    var x = propertyName.substr(0, stringToCheck.length - 1);

    if(x == stringToCheck) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think "Querying" a object properties is possible. You would have to loop through the properties individually and determine if they match. something like this...

```
function findProp(e, prop)
{
    for(var o in e.data){
        if(o.substr(0, prop.length)==prop) //<- you could try the regex or match operation here
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

alert(findProp({data:{addr:{street:"a", sub:"b"}}}, 'addr'));
```

You can then process the property if it findProp returns true...

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function

```
function check(model) {
   var keys = [];
   for (key in model) { 
       if(key.indexOf("addr") > -1) 
           keys.push(key); 
   }
   return keys;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not just

```js
var foo = {'bar':'funtimes'};
if (foo.bar.includes('fun')) {
  console.log('match');
}
```

Comment: Because it is regarding the key, not the value.